# I am trying to open a camera every time view controller is active

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to open the iPhone camera every time I am loading a certain view controller. However it only opens once and if I load the view controller again it doesn't open the camera. How can I open the camera every time I enter the view controller?

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];


  UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
{
    [imagePickerController setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
}

// image picker needs a delegate,
[imagePickerController setDelegate:self];

// Place image picker on the screen
[self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Write above code in following method

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

}
```

Comment: thanks, I thought I did this, but must of been a different version of this viewwillappear and cause it to keep coming up.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to be using `viewDidAppear:` instead of `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 1):

**Write Following Code:**

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.actionsheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Take Photo with Camera", @"Select from Library", nil];
    [self.actionsheet showInView:self.view];

  self.imgPicker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
  self.imgPicker.delegate=self;
  self.imgPicker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
  self.imgPicker.allowsEditing=YES;

}


- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if(buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
            self.imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        else
            self.imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
        [self presentViewController:self.imgPicker animated:YES completion:nil ];

        self.btnBlure.tag = 102;
    }
    else if (buttonIndex==1)
    {
        self.imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
        [self presentViewController:self.imgPicker animated:YES completion:nil ];

        self.btnBlure.tag = 103;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you look at `viewController life cycle`,you can note that

> viewDidLoad() calls only at one time when you loads first time, after
>   that when you switches again to same viewController it does not calls
>   to viewDidLoad. instead of calling to viewDidLoad it calls to `-
>   (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`.
>
> then you have to write your
>   camera opening code in

`- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` method

Now whenever & how many times you push or present your viewController it opens the camera.